# react/scss body background-image becomes [object Object]

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

I'm not sure what is going on, but none of the other questions I've checked have helped, so I presume this is something new. Basically, I'm trying to set a background image to the `<body>` element in an `scss` file I load in Webpack for my `react-dom` project.

Technically everything works just fine, except for that some reason this happens automatically:

[image]

In the `scss` file I have:

```
body {
    background-image: url(static/img/background.jpg) silver;
    background-size: contain;
    color: white;
}
```

I have also tried `url("static/img/background.jpg")` with same results.

The project directory structure is:

[image]

webpack.config.js:

```
let webpack = require('webpack');
let path = require('path');

let BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
let APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

let config = {
    entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: APP_DIR,
        port: 8100,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                include: APP_DIR,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }, {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
            }, {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            }, {
                test: /\.jpg$/,
                loader: 'ignore-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "follow-redirects": "1.2.5",
    "ignore-loader": "0.1.2",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "16.0.0",
    "react-modal": "3.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "webpack": "^3.7.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.1",
    "webpack-windows": "0.0.3"
},
```

I use `ignore-loader` because without it I get this strange error:

```
ERROR in ./src/static/img/background.jpg
Module parse failed: C:\Juha\project\src\static\img\background.jpg Unexpected character '?' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/main.scss 6:62-100
 @ ./src/main.scss
 @ ./src/index.jsx
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8100 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.jsx
```

**Update**
Following the tip to use `file-loader`, it goes a bit further, but still doesn't work fully. It shows the filename and I can open it manually, but it is crossed out in the actual page and does not appear:

[image]

But when I open it directly, it does work:

[image]

Comment: maybe try https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-webpack-loader instead of ignore-loader?

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak I actually just did, and got a similar module loader error: ``ERROR in ./src/static/img/background.jpg
Module parse failed: C:\Juha\project\node_modules\image-webpack-loader\index.js!C:\Juha\project\src\static\i
mg\background.jpg Unexpected character '?' (1:0)``

Comment: try using file-loader for the jpg instead of image loader, I definitely think the problem is how webpack is handling your image

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak hmm, that appears to work as in it shows a randomly generated filename, but it still appears as crossed out and not in the actual page. If I open it directly from localhost:8100/filename.jpg, it appears. I'll update the question to show it better.

Comment: Actually there is this in the console: ``Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg: "http://localhost:8100/759314517c94445b2e9bc6852468a118.jpg".``

Comment: I think that could be due to using ``url()`` instead of ``image()``. I'll try that. **Update**: Nope, same thing.

Comment: Okay, got it working with ``file-loader`` when I use ``background: url("static/img/background.jpg");`` instead of ``background-image: url("static/img/background.jpg");``

Answer (score 1):

Okay, following @RobbieMilejczak 's tip to use `file-loader`, I got it working with this:

scss:

```
body {
    /*
    Note that I use "background" instead of "background-image".
    It seemed to be the issue, for some reason. 
    */
    background: url("static/img/background.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    color: white;
}`
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?/,
            include: APP_DIR,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        }, {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
        }, {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json-loader'
        }, {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader'
        }
    ]
}
```

using:

```
"file-loader": "1.1.5",
```

Answer (score 1):

Import using `url(${background.src})` where `src` contains the path where your image is located.

```
import background from '../public/city.jpg'

      <div
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${background.src})`,
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
      }}
    >
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes around the relative url path for your image without the ignore-loader.

```
body {
    background-image: url("static/img/background.jpg") silver;
    background-size: contain;
    color: white;
}
```

EDIT:

also add publicPath to your webpack config's output.

see: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-publicpath

Comment: Like I mentioned in the post, I also tried it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Put the image or any asset in public folder and use `background: url(/imageName.jpg)`